# React Promise.all not waiting for all promises to resolve before continuing

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have the code below but when i upload a file and parse it the promise.all does not complete before the reload takes place and i cant figure out why, this file contains roughly 380 datapoints but at most 18 are posted before the page reloads

```
      async function beginpost() {
            APIURL = 'http://localhost:8080/new'
            const promises = [];
            const files = e.target.files;
            if (files) {
            Papa.parse(files[0], {
                complete: function(results) {
                for (const element of results.data) {
                    const Data_1 = (`${trimstr(element[0],' (')}`);
                    const Data_2 = (`${element[1]}`);
                    const Data_3 = (`${element[2]}`);
                    const Data_4 = (`${element[3]}`);
                    const Data_5 = (`${element[4]}`);  
                    const Data_6 = (`${element[6]}`);  
                    const Data_7 = (`${element[7]}`);                         
const result = axios.post(APIURL,
{POST_1: ID,
POST_2: Data_1, 
POST_3: Data_2, 
POST_4: Data_3, 
POST_5: Data_4, 
POST_6: Data_5, 
POST_7: Data_6, 
POST_8: Data_7}
)
                        promises.push(result);
                    }
                }
            }})
        }
            const results = await Promise.all(promises)
            window.location.reload(true); //Refresh the page
        }
        beginpost();
```

I have tried placing the reload in the then clause of the promise.all but had the same issue

Comment: From what do you infer that it doesn't work? You reload the window immediately, so you can't check for your console log, I assume. Could it be that not all promises succeed, since you are using `Promise.allSettled()` and not `Promise.all()`???

Comment: This looks like a race condition between the parsing of the CSV, and the waiting for the promises. Maybe add an extra promise that you await for checking whether the parsing is complete and all the promises have been added.

Comment: @SebastianK promises are still pending when the reload takes place, i have also tried both all and allsettled

Comment: @eten this could be the case i will try this thanks

Comment: Yes, that seems likely. Instead of using the callback function, I suggest simply storing the parsing results in s variable, as `Papa.parse` returns the results.

Comment: i stored the parse in an array then looped the array to prevent the race condition thanks all, i have produced an answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kudos to @eten as there was a race condition causing the issue

to resolve this issue first parsed the CSV and created a nested array from the values

```
    const feilds = [];
    const files = e.target.files;
    if (files) {
        Papa.parse(files[0], {
            complete: function(results) {
            for (const element of results.data) {
                const Feild_1= (`${trimstr(element[0],' (')}`);
                const Feild_2 = (`${element[1]}`);
                const Feild_3 = (`${element[2]}`);
                const Feild_4 = (`${element[3]}`);
                const Feild_5 = (`${element[4]}`);  
                const Feild_6 = (`${element[6]}`);  
                const Feild_7 = (`${element[7]}`);  
                feilds.push([Feild_1, Feild_2, Feild_3, Feild_4, Feild_5, Feild_6, Feild_7]);
                }
            }
        }})
    }
```

once i had the array "Feilds" i then looped over the array to start posting the data and wait for all promises to be fulfilled

```
    async function beginpost() {
        APIURL = 'http://localhost:8080/new'
        const promises = [];
            for (const element of feilds) {
                const Data_1 = (`${element[10]}`); 
                const Data_2 = (`${trimstr(element[0],' (')}`);
                const Data_3 = (`${element[1]}`);
                const Data_4 = (`${element[2]}`);
                const Data_5 = (`${element[3]}`);
                const Data_6 = (`${element[4]}`);  
                const Data_7 = (`${element[6]}`);  
                const Data_8 = (`${element[7]}`);  
                    const result = axios.post(APIURL, 
                        {Post_1: Data_1, 
                        Post_2: Data_2,
                        Post_3: Data_3,
                        Post_4: Data_4,
                        Post_5: Data_5,
                        Post_6: Data_6,
                        Post_7: Data_7,
                        Post_8: Data_8
                    })
                    promises.push(result);
            }
        const results = await Promise.all(promises)
        window.location.reload(true); //Refresh the page
    }
    beginpost();
```

Hope this helps others